# Change dired `long-list` format

Tags: emacs

`dired` invoke a long list format with `dired-listing-switches` as `-lBh --group-directories-first`,

`the long list format` is cumbersome for me and it displayed badly in half srceen situation.

As a solution, change `dired-listing-switches` to `-Bh --group-directories-first`,

Consequently, the long-list disappeared, along with it, all functions equipped with dired gone as well. I cannot do any operations on the dired buffer.

It behave exactly as a simple shell in command line.

Is it possible to remove `l` and keep all dired functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep all dired functions" and "all functions equipped with dired gone"? Can you specify the problem a bit better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'dired-hide-details-mode)`

That will list just the file names by default.  You can toggle it with `(` or `M-x dired-hide-details-mode` in a `dired` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html#Dired-Enter) says that the `dired-listing-switches` must contain `-l`, but it does not say why - I'm guessing that the rest of dired assumes that the buffer is in `ls -l` format in order to parse it:

> The variable ‘dired-listing-switches’ specifies the options to give
>   to ‘ls’ for listing the directory; this string *must* contain ‘-l’.